# How can I change outgoing mail configuration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, environment-variables, laravel-5.3

My email setting in env like this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=secret@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

It works. But, I want to change email sender. So I don't use email sender gmail

My boss gives me a new email setting like this :

---

Mail Client Manual Settings

---

Secure SSL/TLS Settings (Recommended)

Username:contact@secretshop.id

Password:secret

---

Incoming Server:

palasik.in-hell.com

IMAP Port: 9xx

POP3 Port: 9xx

---

Outgoing Server:

palasik.in-hell.com

SMTP Port: 465

IMAP, POP3, and SMTP require authentication.

---

Non-SSL Settings (NOT Recommended)

Username:contact@secretshop.id

Password:secret

---

Incoming Server:

mail.secretshop.id

IMAP Port: 1xx

POP3 Port: 1xx

---

Outgoing Server:

mail.secretshop.id

SMTP Port: 587

---

IMAP, POP3, and SMTP require authentication.

---

I want to ask some questions

What is the difference between Secure SSL / TLS Settings and Non-SSL Settings?

what is the difference between incoming Server and Outgoing Server?

What new setting is more suitable?

I tried like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.secretshop.id
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=contact@secretshop.id
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Is it the best choice?

Comment: Have a look at `config/mail.php`, everything you need is documentated there.

Comment: @Insax, I know that. Data in `config/mail.php` is taken from env. For example : `'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD')`. It will get value `secret`

Comment: Then I can't follow your question, if you know all of this, why don't you just set the Settings the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always recommended to use SSL as it is secured & reduces the changes of the sent mail being filtered by the recipient's host as spam.

Most email accounts have two servers:

- one that lets you send emails to other people,
- and another that lets you receive the emails that other people send
  you.

The server that lets you send mail is called an **outgoing**, or SMTP    server.  The server that lets you receive mail is called an **incoming**,    POP, or just Mail server.

---

To change the sender config in Laravel use in .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=palasik.in-hell.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=contact@secretshop.id
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. Can you update your answer, what setting in env? and where does it need to be changed?

Comment: just did @SuccessMan

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I want to ask again :) How to change IMAP port and POP3 port?

Comment: Okay. How if I choose to use Non-SSL setting? Can you update your answer again? If I choose to use Non-SSL, what it will change  IMAP port and POP3 port?

Comment: in that case you need to use tls. simply replace `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` and `MAIL_PORT=<your-tls-port>`

Comment: smtp is very slow process if you are working with Laravel then use API based approach like [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com) they are easy to setup & lightning fast too

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the config on `config/mail.php` or on the `.env` of your app.